# Read in empty element

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I am trying to parse an Iptables XML configuration in Java using the Simple XML framework.

I'm stuck to read in the ACTIONS elements like in this piece of config:

```
   <actions>
       <DROP  />
   </actions>
```

How can I check in my Java that the DROP element was present in the XML file?

Comment: If you are trying just to identify that 'actions' has any 'DROP' child element, use 'actions/drop' or 'not(actions/drop)' XPATH expression

Comment: How can I write that in my code? The SImple XML framework is parsing the XML document. How can I annotate the Java class to check if there is an empty DROP element present inside the actions element?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `actions` is mapped to a class similar to this one:

```
@Root(name = "actions")
public class Actions
{
    @Element(name = "DROP", required = false)
    private String drop;


    // ...

    public String getDrop()
    {
        return drop;
    }
}
```

If you don't want `drop` to be empty you can annotate it as *required*:

```
@Element(name = "DROP", required = true)
private String drop;
```

The parameter `required = true` will throw an exception if `drop` is empty. You can use this if an empty `drop` is not allowed.

A second way is to set `required = false`; then it will be deserialized to `null` if it's empty:

```
@Element(name = "DROP", required = false)
private String drop;

// Test if 'drop' is empty:
Actions a = ...
boolean isEmpty = ( a.getDrop() == null );
```

You now can check whether drop is `null` (= empty) or *not* `null` (= set). You can use this if `drop` may be empty and that's not a problem / required.

As a third way you can implement a **`Converter`** where you implement the serialization / deserialization by your own.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a converter so that an empty element is not returned as null but as an empty string.